# Simple sufficient conditions for matrix positive semidefiniteness?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

I need to show that a complicated $n \times n$ Hermitian matrix is positive semidefinite. I'm wondering if there are simple sufficient conditions that can be used to show this. For instance, if a matrix with positive diagonal is diagonally dominant, then it is positive semidefinite. Other conditions like this would be helpful.

Comment: It is pos. semidefinite iff all its eigenvalues are (real) non-negative, iff all its principal minors are non-negative.

Comment: Right, I guess I should have been more precise with my definition of "simple". Computing the eigenvalues or the determinants of large matrices is not very simple.

Comment: Anything else would imply, imo, either much more information regarding a particular matrix, or else magic...